# TFS SSRS chart for multiple date ranges

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, tfs-reports

I have got following TFS data (for bugs) using reporting service:

*WorkItemCount, CreatedDate, priority and assignedTo.*

I want to display this data in Pie chart (SSRS) which shows number of bugs in 3 ranges (category groups), i.e. #bugs created within last month, between 1 and 3 month old and older then 3 month.

How can I achieve this result? Is it possible to apply filter or customization at chart level to get it done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Create your category group and then right click on it in the chart data viewer. Select category properties. In the General tab, change the function for the Group Expression to something like this:

```
   iif(Date.Value > DateAdd("m", -1, now()), "Within Previous Month", iif(Date.Value > DateAdd("m", -3, now()), "1-3 Months Old", "3+ Months Old"))
```

Comment: You said "Create your category group", what do you mean by it? I have taken fields "Work_Item_Count" in SUM (sigma) Values and "System_CreatedDate" in Category Groups of chart data. I can't see 3 different categories on chart, it is displaying sum of all bugs. What am I missing?

Comment: If System_CreatedDate is in your Category Group area, then you can simply right click on it and edit it as I've directed.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same but it's not working. System_CreatedDate comes as "Text" data type. Is it creating problem? How can I share the data and chart screen shot with you to see the result?

Comment: If it is text, you won't be able to do a meaningful greater than or less than comparison. You need to convert the text to date. The CDate() function is a good bet if your date strings are in an appropriate format. In the function I provided above, you would use CDate(Date.Value) in place of all Date.Value. Note that Date.Value is just a placeholder because I don't know your dataset name, you will use your own dataset and field name in its place. Alternatively, you could handle this on the SQL side by casting to a date data type.

Comment: getting error: conversion from string ".." to type 'Date'. Can you guide me to create calculated member in data set which can categories (group/bucket) the data according to the age? I can create chart on calculated member column.

Comment: You need these values in datetime format, there's really no way around it. If the CDate() function fails, it is likely because the string values are not in the appropriate format. What do the dates look like? I.E. mm/dd/yyyy; month, d, yyyy; etc.

Comment: They are in dd/mm/yyyy format. I am getting these dates using WorkItem.System_CreatedDate in my dataset. MS help document says that it is of DateTime type but when I try to apply filter on these values at chart level, data type is taken as string. I tried to use DateDiff() instead of DateAdd() but same results. Please let me know if I can create another column at data set(with TFSOlap as data source) level which create data like this:
System_CreatedDate            Age
=========================
22/03/2015         1 month old
20/03/2015         1 month old
20/01/2015         3-6 month old

Comment: Also, I added "=" as prefix with group expression suggested by you.

Comment: I don't know anything about SSAS and cannot help you there. You'll have to do some troubleshooting to determine why your dates cannot be converted using the CDate function. I recommend using the isDate() function on your dataset to determine which dates are presenting problems. More information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/2dt118h2(v=vs.84).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The issue caused by the format of the System_CreatedDate which is "dd/MM/yyyy" and not supported as the date type in the report but instead of string type. You need to convert this field to the string format "MM/dd/yyyy" and then using the CDate() function to change it the Date type (because the format "dd/MM/yyyy" which is not support to use directly in the CDate() function, so we need to change it to "MM/dd/yyyy" using the split() function and this format will support to use in the CDate() function).

Details information below for your reference:

1. Right click the dateset to add calculated field(NewSystem_CreateDate) and use expression as below, this calculated field will display the NewSystem_CreateDate which is the datetype and format is 
   "MM/dd/yyyy":

```html
=Cdate(split(Fields!System_CreatedDate.Value,"/")(1) &"/"& split(Fields!System_CreatedDate.Value,"/")(0)&"/"&split(Fields!System_CreatedDate.Value,"/")(2))
```

2. Modify the first expression you have provided and change the "System_CreatedDate" to the Calculated field "System_CreatedDate":

```html
=iif(Fields!NewSystem_CreatedDate.Value> DateAdd("m", -1, now), "Within Previous Month", iif(Fields!NewSystem_CreatedDate.Value > DateAdd("m", -3, now), "1-3 Months Old", "3+ Months Old"))
```

Please refer this link for any other details:
[bug Age](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/17eaf1ad-f7e4-4205-a8f1-4bc850743949/tfs-ssrs-bug-age-report?forum=sqlreportingservices&prof=required)